# Phonegap on iOS: The browser does not support MediaStreamTrack

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I wrote a `javascript`/`HTML5` app that requires reading the user's microphone and playing a short `mp3` if  the amplitude reaches a certain value.

I'm not all that experienced with javascript, but I found a library that allows me to read the user's microphone amplitude. [Here](http://p5js.org/learn/examples/Sound_Mic_Input.php) is a link to the library.

I then used the following code to play the mp3:

```
var audio = new Audio('a.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Below is a trimmed down example of what is going on and how it fits together:

```
var mic = new p5.AudioIn();
var Timer;

function start()
{
   Timer = setInterval(tick, 100);
   mic.start();
}

function stop()
{
  clearInterval(Timer);
  mic.stop();
}

function playIt()
{
    clearInterval(Timer);
    mic.stop();
    var audio = new Audio('a.mp3');
    audio.play();
    alarmTimeout = setTimeout(start, 10000);
}

function tick()
{

    var p = parseInt(mic.getLevel()*100);

    if (p > 80)
    {

        playIt();
    }
}
```

The app runs perfectly in the browser (I've only tested Chrome), but I wanted to use `phonegap` to run this app as a native `iOS` app.

When I copied over my HTML/javascript and ran it I got the error in the title saying `The browser does not support MediaStreamTrack`. I'm not entirely sure what that error means, but I'm wondering if there's a more "phonegap-friendly" way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [**iosrtc plugin**](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) to bring WebRTC to iOS. That alone may make the code compatible. It uses `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` to find the microphone device, but `getSources` is now deprecated in favor of `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, so you may need to shim out `getSources` manually, using `enumerateDevices` internally so that it returns correctly. I believe the plugin does this already, though.